# Google App Engine - Wordpress Importer

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I have recently installed Wordpress on Google App Engine for PHP.  Remote image uploading works - so it appears bucket storage is set up correctly.  Also, I can create and delete pages and posts - so cloud SQL is working right.

The problem is - the Wordpress remote importer (a plugin that uses an XML file to add content to the database) does not work - the error message I get is:

> File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error
>   could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by
>   post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in
>   php.ini.

Should I be able to use the Wordpress Importer plugin in App Engine?  If so, what are steps I could take to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a problem that may be related:

It turns out that the `app.yaml` file that Google recommends does not handle routing well for some Wordpress themes and plugins.

Here is a sample of the `app.yaml` lines I had to change/add:

```
handlers:
    - url: /wp-content/themes/fuse/library/css/custom.css.php
      script: wordpress/wp-content/themes/fuse/library/css/custom.css.php

    - url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|ttf$|jpg$|jpeg$|otf$|woff$|svg$))
      static_files: wordpress/\1
      upload: wordpress/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$|ttf$|jpg$|jpeg$|otf$|woff$|svg$))
      application_readable: true
```

The above lines change App Engine routing to fix two separate problems:

- Some urls that should cause a script to run, start a download
- Some urls that should start a file download, cause a dead-end

For fixing the Wordpress Importer, I also tried adding the line `upload_max_filesize = 8M` to my `php.ini` file.  That edit did not appear to fix the problem.

I suspect that the Wordpress importer should work on App Engine - but I can't say for sure.  Hopefully someone with more expertise will give a better answer.